# Vuetify 2 - 10 showing up in pagination options even though set a new array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In vuetify 2, I show a data table and I set the pagination options to be [50,60,70], but what shows on the page is [10,50,60,70]. Somehow it combines the default 10 into the list.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NQRRzY?&editable=true&editors=101

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        :options.sync="options"
        :server-items-length="totalDesserts"
        :loading="loading"
        class="elevation-1"
        :footer-props="{itemsPerPageOptions : [50,60,70]}"
      ></v-data-table>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      totalDesserts: 0,
      desserts: [],
      loading: true,
      options: {},
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
    }
  },
  watch: {
    options: {
      handler () {
        this.getDataFromApi()
          .then(data => {
            this.desserts = data.items
            this.totalDesserts = data.total
          })
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getDataFromApi()
      .then(data => {
        this.desserts = data.items
        this.totalDesserts = data.total
      })
  },
  methods: {
    getDataFromApi () {
      this.loading = true
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const { sortBy, descending, page, itemsPerPage } = this.options

        let items = this.getDesserts()
        const total = items.length

        if (this.options.sortBy) {
          items = items.sort((a, b) => {
            const sortA = a[sortBy]
            const sortB = b[sortBy]

            if (descending) {
              if (sortA < sortB) return 1
              if (sortA > sortB) return -1
              return 0
            } else {
              if (sortA < sortB) return -1
              if (sortA > sortB) return 1
              return 0
            }
          })
        }

        if (itemsPerPage > 0) {
          items = items.slice((page - 1) * itemsPerPage, page * itemsPerPage)
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.loading = false
          resolve({
            items,
            total,
          })
        }, 1000)
      })
    },
    getDesserts () {
      return [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ]
    },
  },
})
```

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

**It is because you only have 10 items. I made a pen to show you it works fine with smaller numbers.** Run code snippet in expanded view.

[here is a pen](https://codepen.io/rveruna/pen/BaBQYOy)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      name: "",
      calories: "",
      fat: "",
      carbs: "",
      desserts: [{
          name: "Frozen Yogurt",
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24
        },
        {
          name: "Ice cream sandwich",
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37
        },
        {
          name: "Eclair",
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23
        },
        {
          name: "Cupcake",
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67
        },
        {
          name: "Gingerbread",
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49
        },
        {
          name: "Jelly bean",
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94
        },
        {
          name: "Lollipop",
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98
        },
        {
          name: "Honeycomb",
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87
        },
        {
          name: "Donut",
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51
        },
        {
          name: "KitKat",
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    headers() {
      return [{
          text: "Dessert (100g serving)",
          align: "left",
          sortable: false,
          value: "name",
          filter: f => {
            return (f + '').toLowerCase().includes(this['name'].toLowerCase())
          }
        },
        {
          text: "Calories",
          value: "calories",
          filter: value => {
            if (!this.calories) return true;
            return value < parseInt(this.calories);
          }
        },
        {
          text: "Fat (g)",
          value: "fat",
          filter: value => {
            if (!this.fat) return true;
            return value < parseInt(this.fat);
          }
        },
        {
          text: "Carbs (g)",
          value: "carbs",
          filter: value => {
            if (!this.carbs) return true;
            return value == parseInt(this.carbs);
          }
        }
      ];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.0-alpha.18/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.0-alpha.18/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <template>
      <div>
        <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        item-key="name"
        :items="desserts"
        :footer-props="{'items-per-page-options': [ 4, 8, 10]}"
      ></v-data-table>
      </div>
    </template>
  </v-app>
</div>
```